# How do I hide the Workplaces and Applications buttons in the top bar of Dash to Panel?

Tags: 20.10

guys! I think the title is pretty telling. How do I do it? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should have an application named `gnome-extensions-app` on your system. Open that and deactivate the corresponding extensions, which should be 'Applications Menu' and 'Places Status Indicator'.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue finding where to disable them on Pop os.

To disable the workspaces and applications buttons go to:
`Settings > Desktop > General`

Under the subcategory `Top Bar` you should see `Show Workspaces Button` and `Show Applications Button`.

Disabling both will hide them.

[Link to the image as I need 10 rep to embed it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hXkV.png)

Comment: There is no citations or documentation for this type of issue...